# Stop alamofire datarequest completion handler from executing

Tags: session, swift3, timeout, alamofire

I need to handle session time out in alamofire. Is there a way to stop the completion handler in alamofire request from executing when I get a 401 error ?

Answer (score 0):

Just cancel the request delegate queue operations

self.delegate.queue.cancelAllOperations()